# How to Add max attribute to InputDate component

Tags: blazor

I have a standard `<inputDate/>` component on my  Editform.

When rendered, it displays the correct watermark of `yyyy-mm-dd`, and you can select a date correctly.
However, when you try type in a value, the year extends to 6 digits, instead of four. In the documentation of [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min_date) it say add max attribute to the input. how to add on `<inputDate/>` component

Answer (score 3):

All components in Blazor, which inherit from `InputBase` support attribute pass-through. What that means is whatever non-known parameter you would define for the component, it'll be rendered in the final HTML tag as is. As an example, if your InputDate component is defined like `<InputDate @bind-value="model.value" foo="bla" />`, it'll be rendered as `<input foo="bla" type="date" class="valid">`.

For your particular situation, you can now use this knowledge to define an extra `max` parameter for your `InputDate` component set to the value you want it to be, and it'll be rendered.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

do you have a screen shot of 6 digits?

Editform is controlled by dataannotations

```
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/2/2004", "3/4/2004",
    ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
public object SellEndDate;
```

Comment: I think this is probably the better suggestion because it will create a Blazor style validation error which can appear in `<ValidationSummary>` etc.